# maven-war-plugin always running even without child pom.xml reference...why?

Tags: maven, plugins, war, pom.xml

I am specifying:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>        
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <configuration>         
                        <outputDirectory>C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

.
.
.

However, even though I do not specify anything in the respective children pom.xml, the war file is still being moved to that output directory.

As far as I know, pluginManagement is only there for reference from the children pom right?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

By default Maven will invoke the maven-war-plugin war:war goal as part of the package phase if you specify `<packaging>war</packaging>` in your pom.xml

Since you have a `<pluginManagement>` stanza for maven-war-plugin specifying a custom `<outputDirectory>` in your parent pom.xml your child pom.xml will use this property when you run the package phase.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html